# Signed url for gcp bucket object fails with access denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, storage, bucket, signed-url

As I generate a signed download url with a service account for an object within a storage gcp bucket, I expect it to be usable by anyone without authentication. However, I keep getting "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object". What am I doing wrong?

```
url, err := gcs.SignedURL(bktName, so.Name(), &gcs.SignedURLOptions{
    GoogleAccessID: serviceAccountName,
    Method:         "GET",
    Expires:        time.Now().Add(duration),
    ContentType:    md.RenditionMetadata[0].ContentType,
    Headers:        []string{fmt.Sprintf("x-goog-meta-filename: %s", md.RenditionMetadata[0].FileName)},
    SignBytes: func(b []byte) ([]byte, error) {
        signedBlob, err := iam.SignBlob(s.GoogleIamService(), serviceAccountName, b)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return []byte(signedBlob), err
    },
})
```

The service account I'm using has Storage Object Creator and Storage Object Viewer roles ...

Comment: If I make the object public, it seems to work, but that is unacceptable, a signed url with duration is absolutely necessary ...

Answer (score 1):

Follow the guide for Creating a signed URL to download an object:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-generate-signed-url-v4

Alternatively, you can make use of gsutil commands to create signed URl:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/signurl

Answer (score 1):

if you specify headers when creating a signed url,
you must include them when 'curling' the generated url ;-)